# bbpress plug-ins and buddypress

Tags: buddypress, bbpress, moderation

Is it possible to use the standalone bbpress plug-ins with a buddypress site - using bbpress forums site-wide and disabling the buddypress forums. I need to add moderation. I have decided not to use buddypress forums.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it is possible.  However, your buddypress theme must be compatible with bbpress or else /forums won't be setup correctly.

Reference: http://devpress.com/blog/how-to-make-a-site-like-devpress/

> bbPress for Forums or Message Board Although BuddyPress has group
>   forums, I don’t have it enabled on DevPress. It’s because I prefer
>   having a central forum for interaction and support instead of having a
>   forum for each group. When DevPress get to 10,000 members or more then
>   it would make sense to turn on group specific forums. When nurturing a
>   community or social network, it’s important to make your site not feel
>   empty. Only when you have more members than you can handle do you let
>   everything go wild. But before that, you need to have one central
>   place for member interaction.

Comment: Is this answer still true? If so, is there a recommended BuddyPress theme?